# Facebook Ads API: (#10) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

I have facebook app with status `Live and available to all users`. When I login through this app on my site I get `access_token` for my facebook user. And with this access_token I can read with Ads API next methods (for my own ad campaigns):

- /me/adaccounts
- /act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/agroups

But when someone else login on my site (and confirms all permissions) and I get his/her access_token I can't perform second api call. I get this error **(#10) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action**. But I can get account ids. So, first method works, second not. How to fix this?

P.S. Status of app in `App details` tab is `Unapproved` (lightblue circle).

P.P.S. After adding that user to app's developers all is ok with second method (adcampaigns).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your app is most likely in development Tier for Ads API Access

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/access#limits

You need to apply for higher levels

[image: Apply for Basic Level]

Answer (score 1):

Some time its happen when you reach the limit of Marketing API Access.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access

Suppose your application have basic Marketing API Access Levels (In Basic, further test, iterate, build an app with up to 25 external accounts.) and you reach limit of ad account. When your new ad account(s) will request Facebook Ads API access then facebook send you mention error response.

To check your ad account(s) and their limit
Facebook APP -> Settings -> Advance tab -> Advertising Accounts section -> Ads Api button

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/settings/advanced/