# (#10) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using Graph API Explorer. i am trying to get suggested bid based on selected audience and area i am getting error like this (**(#10) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action**). this is under development only. not a live account

Comment: Can you provide more information? For example, API request sample, permissions that you have, etc could be useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Ads API: (#10) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604001/facebook-ads-api-10-you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-perform-this-a)