# Permissions error: Connect to Business Manager to Create This Audience while creating facebook custom audience using ruby sdk

Tags: ruby, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to create custom audience using `facebook-ruby-business-sdk`. I am using below code,

```
require 'facebook_ads'

ad_acc = FacebookAds::AdAccount.get('act_351195241', 'name', {
access_token: "<USER_ACCESS_TOKEN>", app_secret: "<APP_SECRET_KEY>"
})

ca = ad_acc.customaudiences.create({
  name: 'Customers from CRM',
  subtype: 'CUSTOM',
  description: 'CA from API',
  customer_file_source: 'USER_PROVIDED_ONLY',
})

users = [['FirstName', 'test1@example.com', 'LastName1'],
    ['FirstNameTest', 'test2@example.com', 'LastNameTest']]

schema = ["FN","EMAIL","LN"]

ca.add_user(users, schema)
```

And I am getting this error `Permissions error: Connect to Business Manager to Create This Audience` whereas I have already created a business manager account and attached this to it.

I am struck here and it would be great if anyone can help me out in this.

Comment: Your App does not have the higher level access required for this. You need to upgrade the level. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27604973/5306420 might help you.

Comment: higher level access to get ads_read and ads_management permission?

Comment: Could not find place to add higher level permission. Is it adding ads_read and ads_management access under Marketing API settings?

Answer (score 0):

Could not find place to add higher level permission. Is it adding ads_read and ads_management access under Marketing API settings? [IS THIS the ONE?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOGWB.png)